# Application won't start due to gunicorn AppImportError

Tags: python

I created a pretty basic application using Python and Dash (datatables, html, etc.). I'm trying to run the application to deploy using gunicorn and Render, but I keep getting an error when I try to deploy it, below is the error:

```
File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", 
line 430, in import_app    raise 
AppImportError("Application object must be callable.")gunicorn.errors.AppImportError: 
Application object must be callable.
```

Every question or piece of documentation I find indicates that it could be something wrong with the naming of files / objects that I have used. Is it possible that the Dash functionality for creating a Dash table being

```
app = Dash(__ name__)
```

is causing issues with gunicorn's call to run an application? (see below)

```
gunicorn Fantasy_Stats_Tracking:app
```

Any help would be amazing! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The docs seems to say that you need to call `app.server` and not just `app` with Gunicorn in order for it to work.

`gunicorn Fantasy_Stats_Tracking:app.server` *should* do the trick, given that your Python file is named `Fantasy_Stats_Tracking.py`.
[ref1](https://fizzy.cc/deploy-dash-on-server/) [ref2](https://dash.plotly.com/deployment)

Comment: Thanks for answering, unfortunately this didn't work through. I got two errors from it: "Failed to parse %r as an attribute name or function call" and "Failed to parse  app.server as an attribute name or function call.

Comment: Hmm, if you create a variable after `app`, `server=app.server`, and run gunicorn with `gunicorn Fantasy_Stats_Tracking:server`, does it help? reference: https://community.plotly.com/t/deploy-dash-to-heroku-error-failed-to-parse-app-server-as-an-attribute-name-or-function-call/47909

Comment: Give also this solution a go if the previous is no help: https://community.plotly.com/t/deploy-dash-to-heroku-error-failed-to-parse-app-server-as-an-attribute-name-or-function-call/47909/7

Comment: Hi jolammi, thanks again for the response - I stepped away from the project yesterday but back on it now. I tried adding server=app.server, and changed the Procfile to reflect what you said.

Comment: It seems like there is something wrong with the deployment reading the Procfile, as I updated it but it doesn't seem like it's reading the updates